# Minimum distance to plot points on UIMapview

Tags: iphone, ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkmapview

my query is whats the minimum distance required to plot point on a UIMAPVIEW, so that they could be shown as distinct points.
For e.g., suppose if there are users in same apartment, their would be hardly any distance between their latitude-longitude. So how do i differentiate them !

Answer (score 1):

There are usually two ways - one is clustering, which means you use a marker with a number that indicates how many underlying markers there are. When tapping on that, the user is then shown the separate markers (or a recursive zoom-in that splits the markers up more and more). Superpin (www.getsuperpin.com) is one example, but there are others out there.

Another approach is to actually offset the marker from its real location. For this, you need some kind of distribution algorithm that offsets it just enough - that is, set the markers as close together as possible while still giving them enough surface area to be seen/touched. For this, we use Fibonacci's Sunflower patten. What you'd have to do is identify all the Annotations that have the same coordinate, group them, and then draw each group in a sequence while offsetting one from the other - for ex. have some code that iterates along a spiral shape and drops down markers along that spiral.

Can put up sample code etc to help if you're wanting to go with the second approach, let me know.

EDIT: I found some code we wrote for this, but it's not objective C. Can you read it?

```
class SunFlower
{
    static $SEED_RADIUS = 2;
    static $SCALE_FACTOR = 4;
    static $PI2 = 6.28318531; // PI * 2
    static $PHI = 1.61803399; // (sqrt(5)+1) / 2

    public static function calcPos($xc, $yc, $factor, $i)
    {
        $theta = $i * SunFlower::$PI2 / SunFlower::$PHI;
        $r = sqrt($i) * $factor;
        $x = $xc + $r * cos($theta);
        $y = $yc - $r * sin($theta);

        if ($i == 1) {
            $y += ($factor * 0.5);
        }

        return array($x, $y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation Jai, I have a doubt in first approach, even if we cluster points and display them, how could they be distinguished !
The points which i would be plotting would be sent by user's current location and if 2 users are in same room, would it be possible to distinguish the !

Comment: About 2nd approach, I didnt understand much about this, it would be really helpful if u put up the second approach !
Regards.

Comment: I'm trying to find the code I used for the sunflower pattern - will post soon. Just a heads up though, it will offset the markers from the actual location so the markers will technically be in the 'wrong' place

Comment: Sure Jai, would we looking forward towards it..!

Comment: Hey Jgd I've posted the code into the response, let me know if you need any further help

Comment: Thanks Jai, will try working with it soon, need to integrate this part in a bit later stage of my project...Thanks alot man :)